# ¿Como eliminar un valor de una tabla html dependiendo del valor seleccionado con un input check, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.

Actualmente tengo 2 tablas de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla prestamos la genero dinamicamente de la siguiente forma:

```
var prestamos_creditos = $('.prestamos_creditos');
                    $.each(response.data, function(index,value){
                        $('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td noPrestamo').text(value.Numero_Prestamo))
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td fiador').text(value.Cod_Cliente_P))
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td montoPrestamo').text(value.Saldo.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')))
                            .append('<div class="monto_prestamo_seleccionado" style="display:none">' + value.Saldo + '</div>')
                            .append('<div class="fecha_prestamo" style="display:none">' + value.Fecha + '</div>')
                            .append('<div class="numero_prestamo" style="display:none">' + value.Numero_Prestamo + '</div>')
                            .append('<div class="cod_cliente_prestamo" style="display:none">' + value.Cod_Cliente_P + '</div>')
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td classCantidad')
                                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                            .append('<input type="checkbox" name="prestamo" class="prestamo" value="' + value.Cod_Tipo_Prestamo + '"/>')
                                            .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                            .appendTo(prestamos_creditos);
                    });
```

En la tabla "Préstamos de crédito asignados a tu código" selecciono un prestamo, lo cual va llenando la tabla "Formas de pago seleccionadas".

```
function formaspagoSeleccionadas(nombre_forma_pago, cantPago,resultado, fecha_prestamo, numero_documento, cod_cliente){
        console.log("FUNCION, FORMAS PAGOS SELECCIONADOS: ");
        console.log(nombre_forma_pago);
        console.log(cantPago);
        console.log(resultado);
        console.log(fecha_prestamo);
        console.log(numero_documento);
        console.log(cod_cliente);

        let formas_pagos_seleccionados = $('.formas_pagos_seleccionados');
        $('<tr class="pagos"/>')
            .append($('<td>/').addClass('nuevo-td')
                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-radio item-content').text(nombre_forma_pago)))
            .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(cantPago))
            .append('<div class="fecha_prestamo" style="display:none">' + fecha_prestamo + '</div>')
            .append('<div class="numero_documento" style="display:none">' + numero_documento + '</div>')
            .append('<div class="cod_cliente" style="display:none">' + cod_cliente + '</div>')
            .append('<div class="monto" style="display:none">' + cantPago + '</div>')
            .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell').append('<button value="' + resultado + '" type="button" class="eliminarformaPago button button-fill button-raised button-circle" title="Comment"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>'))
            .appendTo(formas_pagos_seleccionados);
        console.log("Este es el resultado despues de llenar la tabla: "+resultado);
        $('.saldo_pendiente').text(resultado.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
    }
```

En la tabla formas de pago selecionadas tengo un boton para borrar el registro, para lo cual tengo la siguiente función:

```
$$('.formas_pagos_seleccionados').on('click', '.eliminarformaPago', function(){
        console.log("Eliminar forma de pago");
        let forma_pago = $(this).closest('tr');
        let fecha_prestamo = forma_pago.find('.fecha_prestamo').text();
        let numero_documento = forma_pago.find('.numero_documento').text();
        let cod_cliente      = forma_pago.find('.cod_cliente').text();
        let monto            = forma_pago.find('.monto').text();
        let cod_banco;
        console.log(idPedido);
        console.log(cod_forma_pago);
        console.log(monto);
        console.log(cod_banco);
        console.log(fecha_prestamo);
        console.log(numero_documento);
        console.log(cod_cliente); 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

El detalle que quiero resolver es al momento de quitar el check del prestamo que tenga seleccionado en la tabla "Prestamos de crédito asignados a tu codigo" de igual forma elimine automaticamente el registro de la tabla "Formas de pago seleccionadas".
Para este caso seleccione el prestamo 0001, y se agrego en la otra tabla, entonces al quitar el check de 0001 se debe eliminar el registro 0001 de la tabla "formas de pago seleccionadas"

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo que hice fue emular tu dos tablas ya creadas y cree un evento **change** a los **checkbox**, este evento lo puedes integrar a la funcionalidad que ya tienes, cual fue mi idea? bueno en el evento **change** evaluó si el **chekcbox** esta destildado así:

```
if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
```

De ser positivo obtengo su valor `let valor = $(this).val();` y luego busco el **td** en la tabla de **"Formas de Pago"** que contenga como texto el valor del **checkbox** así:

```
$("#formas").find(`td:contains('${valor}')`).parent().remove();
```

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  
  if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
    let valor = $(this).val();
    $("#formas").find(`td:contains('${valor}')`).parent().remove();
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
#formas{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="prestamos" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Préstamo de Crédito</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>No. Prestamo</th>
      <th>Fiador</th>
      <th>Monto</th>
      <th>Seleccionar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>DDDDDDDD</td>
      <td>55,000.00</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked value="0001">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0002</td>
      <td>D61466</td>
      <td>50,000.00</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked value="0002">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="formas" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Formas de Pago</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Forma de pago</th>
      <th>Pago</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0002</td>
      <td>6004</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>6000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Claro yo lo hice lo más genérico posible pero quizás en vez de buscarlo por el contenido dle td a la fila o al tr de la tabla "Formas de Pago" le colocas un pseudo atributo que haga referencia al valor del **checkbox** para luego borrarlo, es la misma filosofía, quedaría algo así:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  
  if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
    let valor = $(this).val();
    $("#formas").find(`tr[data-id="${valor}"]`).remove(); 
  }
  
});
```

```css
#formas{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="prestamos" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Préstamo de Crédito</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>No. Prestamo</th>
      <th>Fiador</th>
      <th>Monto</th>
      <th>Seleccionar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>DDDDDDDD</td>
      <td>55,000.00</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked value="0001">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0002</td>
      <td>D61466</td>
      <td>50,000.00</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked value="0002">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="formas" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Formas de Pago</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Forma de pago</th>
      <th>Pago</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="0001">
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="0002">
      <td>0002</td>
      <td>6004</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="0001">
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>6000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Si te fijas a los **tr** de la tabla "Formas de pago" le agrege un pseudo atributo llamado **data-id** el cual contendré el valor del **checkbox** que quieres hacer referencia, ahí puedes colocar el id del pago etc y nombrar ese atributo como mejor te plazca, espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias David, me ha servidor mucho.

Comment: David perdona la molestía y perdon por el abuso, como podría ir haciendote preguntas especificamente a tu persona.  En la mayoria de preguntas que he hecho me has apoyado.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que si lo elimina de la tabla "Formas de pago seleccionados" quite el deseleccione el input en la tabla "Prestamos de credito"

Comment: @JG_GJ mi info esta en mi perfil para cualquier duda